# Sorting problem- n/k intervals of size k each

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

Given is an array of size *n* which was divided to *n/k* intervals of size *k* each.  The values in each interval are bigger than the ones in the interval to its left and smaller than the ones in the interval to its right.  I want to sort those values in the minimum time that I can.

The naive solution that I thought of is just to sort all the values in each interval which will "cost" *O(k log k)*, for a total cost for all the *n/k* intervals of *O(n log k)*.  I wonder if there's something more efficient.

Now I know that in each interval I have no more than *log log k* different values, I need to come up with a quicker algorithm.  I'd love your help with this.

Thanks!

Comment: Your current approach if you using balanced binary tree takes O(n logloglog(k)) because for sorting ur binary search tree depth is at most O(log (log log k)) so for one of the intervals it takes O(k log log log k) and I think this approach is fast enough, Also there isn't any specific relation in your intervals, to improve n * X to g(n) * X, So I think you can't reduce `n`.

Comment: With `n\k`, do you mean `n/k`, i.e. "n divided by k"?

Comment: @Svante: yeah, this is what i meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an extremely ugly answer:

```
1. Take the first interval;
2. Since logK should be small, we allocate logK binary tree nodes, and we place the first element in the middle;
3. For the rest of the elements, we use method similar to binary search to search if it is already included, or we add this element;
4. Produce a sorted list with all the values in the interval;
5. Use Counting Sort with this list on the interval;
6. Do this for all the intervals.
```

The time used for 2,3 is O(K*logloglogK) since the search takes at most logloglogK (log on the loglogK elements) and repeated for K times. 4 use at most O(loglogK) time to walk through all the nodes with values. 5 takes O(K) time, similar to the Counting Sort. So the total time should be O(nlogloglogK).

Any question is welcomed since I am really sleepy and cannot guarantee that I am thinking straightly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) or [bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) on each interval costing `O(k)`
for each one, for a total cost of  `O(n/k * k) = O(n)`

Then merge each interval together costing `O(n)` in total. Your algorithm would then be a `O(n) + O(n) = O(n)` algorithm.

Note: if you could take advantage of parallelism, you could sort all of the intervals in parallel for a total cost of `O(k)`. Although your algorithm would still be `O(n)` (because of the merge), it will have smaller constant factors.